# Cannot start nuxt: Only URLs with a scheme in: file and data are supported by the default ESM loader

Tags: nuxt.js

When i remove some packages in my Project , and cleaned the Cache , and rm -rf the Node Modules
Installed new Dependencies and Nuxt, then appear this error.

How to fix it ?

```
 Cannot start nuxt:  Only URLs with a scheme in: file and data are supported by the default ESM loader. On Windows, absolute paths must be valid file:// URLs. Received protocol 'd:'

  at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
  at throwIfUnsupportedURLScheme (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1059:11)                                                                  13:59:57  
  at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1135:3)
  at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
  at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:838:30)
  at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
  at ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:525:22)
  at importModuleDynamically (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:110:35)
  at importModuleDynamicallyCallback (node:internal/process/esm_loader:35:14)
  at loadBuilder (/D:/IAICB-72/IAICB-71/node_modules/nuxt3/dist/index.mjs:2966:5)
```

Cleaned the Cache , rmoved and installed the Dependencies

Comment: Using `NPM` or `yarn`?

Comment: in time use NPM

Answer (score 1):

Same issue. I comment one by one the nuxt module installed to find out it's the @nuxtjs/robots modules who create the bug for me.

Comment: You can use this workaround https://github.com/nuxt-modules/robots/issues/86#issuecomment-1366121300 Keep `@nuxtjs/robots` as a module in your config, add that file with your specific settings and restart your dev server.